# Specifying a year range in daterangepicker

Tags: daterangepicker

I want to specify a given daterange in the daterangepicker. I have the following in the jQuery section in the code. However, in the drop down, I get the 1966 to 2021 by default. How to change it?

```
    $('input[name="startDate"]').daterangepicker({
        locale: {
            format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY'
        },
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        datepickerOptions: {
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear  : true,
            yearRange: "1986:2037"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      var d = new Date();
      var todayDate = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
      $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
      showDropdowns: true,
      minDate: '06/01/1950',
      maxDate: todayDate,
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
```

This one worked for me

Comment: Please add some explanation why the askers code was wrong and what way necessary to fix it.